# How can I describe someone that acts like they don't care about others opinions, but does.

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, story

I am writing a book and this character cares about his friends but doesn't like to show it, he acts like he doesn't care about them, but in privet he is like a dad to them. He wants to protect them but he doesn't want to ruin his reputation as a bad boy.

Comment: Where is your research, please? What did your dictionaries or thesauruses, let alone search engines, suggest?

Comment: Consider "stealth altruist" (not a single-word however).

Comment: [writers.SE] might be a better forum for your question.

Comment: Your character is perhaps dissimulating, pretending, deceiving, feigning, acting, dissembling, masquerading, posing, posturing, shamming, faking, and/or bluffing.

Comment: The character is reserved in public to maintain a facade, but affable in private.

Answer (score 1):

The word aloof means "removed or distant either physically or emotionally an aloof, unfriendly manner".

Comment: Yes, DAF, but how is that related to the Question, please?

Comment: This article mentions aloofness in this context. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial

Comment: @Bread 'In this context' is hardly felicitous here. 'A feeling of aloofness' doesn't even demand any outward demonstration, and is presented as a possible result rather than a motivating force.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth ~ The question asked for a *description* ("how can I describe someone who...") of a personality type or behavior, not a verb for it. And the motivation for the behavior is already provided within the question. It just so happens that aloofness is a key feature of the sort of psychological state (narcissistic defense) which might be involved in such behavior.

Comment: @Bread 'How can I describe someone that acts like they don't care about others opinions, ***but does***'[?] 'Aloof' certainly does not connote the secret underlying caring OP asks be referenced here for me, and I doubt it does for 95+% of the Anglophone population. It is not even hinted at in the dictionaries I've checked.

Comment: "My friend is so aloof you wouldn't guess he really cares about people." -- "at a distance but within view" (1530s) and, figuratively, "apart, withdrawn, without community spirit" -- @Edwin Ashworth ~ There is nothing about the word aloof to suggest a lack of ***caring***.

Comment: Neither is there anything about the word 'aloof' to suggest that the referent does not carry a handkerchief.  Do we therefore assume that people who are aloof should be assumed to have one?

Comment: You don't have to assume anything as long as you have context, which is conveniently supplied in the question. The word aloof was never intended to stand alone; it was to be included in the description of a character for a story.

Answer (score 1):

Such behavior may be characterized as a type of [narcissistic defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_defences#Defence_sequences) mechanism or process which could involve *denial and/or repression*. So you might say that the person is **in denial**, or that he is emotionally **repressed**.

From *Wikipedia*:

> Denial also could mean denying the happening of an event or the reliability of information, which can lead to a feeling of aloofness and to the ignoring of possibly beneficial information.
>
> The subject may use:
>
> simple **denial**: deny the reality of the unpleasant fact altogether...
>
> **Repression** is a key concept of psychoanalysis, where it is understood as a defence mechanism that "ensures that what is unacceptable to the conscious mind, and would if recalled arouse anxiety, is prevented from entering into it.

- I know someone who cares about his friends but refuses to show it; he's **in denial** about his feelings.
- I know someone who cares about his friends but insists it isn't so; he has **repressed** those feelings.